# How to convert DateTime variable to represent date in a particular format?

Tags: c#

I have a string variable that represents a date:

```
String Arrival = "03-05-2013 00:00:00";//format is dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

I need to convert this to a DateTime variable holding date in the exact same format(dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss). So, I tried parsing the string variable:

```
DateTime Arr = DateTime.ParseExact(Arrival,"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, it turns out that variable Arr holds a datetime value that has a formatting that is different (It held the value "3/5/2013 12:00:00 AM").
Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: What was wrong with the answers you got last time you asked the question?

Answer (score 1):

`Arr` itself does not "have" any formatting because it is a `DateTime` value, not a string. When you try to display it what gets displayed is the result of `DateTime.ToString()`, which as [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) says is the same as `DateTime.ToString("G")` (and that in turn is affected by the executing thread's current culture).

If you want to display it in a particular format, use `Arr.ToString("format specification")` -- see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).